# SFDX - force:source:convert command not including label, sharingmodel, name in CustomObject

Tags: custom-object, salesforcedx, metadata-api

I only want to deploy a new CustomField to my Sandbox org.

My initial package.xml is using the CustomField metadata type to pull my new field from my development organization.

However, when I issue the force:source:convert command (to commit changes to source control) and try to deploy the converted CustomObject metadata.xml (via ANT), the Metadata API complains that the CustomObject definition is missing the attributes: Label, PluralLabel, SharingModel, Name & Deployment status.

I added the tags manually, but I'd like to know if there is something I can do in the future to automatically pull these metadata attributes if I want to only deploy certain aspects of a custom object?

The problem with specifying the entire object in the package.xml (when pulling from my DEV org) is I get a ton of stuff not related to my project. (for example, other fields i'm not working on) But it seems like specifying the entire object is the only way to have sfdx generate the object specific metadata attribute so that the convert command can include those tags in the output CustomObject .xml.

Comment: Could be a bug in salesforce cli ? Have you raised it? You can get salesforce attention here (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli)